# Logging JSON request and response for jersey

Tags: java, jersey, aop, jax-rs, aspectj

I have a JAVA web application application, which exposes RESTful apis. My requirement is to log all the JSON requests and responses that are handled by the server. 
Is there any parameter like `-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true` for JAX-WS?

I am also exploring AOP approach. What method signature should I add in the AOP pattern?

I am using Tomcat server and jersey for the JAX-RS implementation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use [LoggingFilter](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/index.html?com/sun/jersey/api/client/filter/LoggingFilter.html). Just add the following to your web.xml:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
  <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
  <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Tried to add this on Glassfish 4.1. Didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!-- Enable Jersey tracing support in Glassfish -->
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

This worked for me (Jersey 2.x)